# What is difference between MemoryCache vs ObjectCache in .net 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

What is difference between .NET framework 4.0 `MemoryCache` vs `ObjectCache`?
Where to use which object?

Comment: MemoryCache is the concrete implementation of ObjectCache. From a design point of view, ObjectCache is abstract and demonstrates how a cache should be built. MemoryCache is the actual implementation of this.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

ObjectCache is the abstract class that demonstrates how you should build a Cache that adheres to the rules the person who wrote ObjectCache wants you to obey. You cannot instantiate ObjectCache directly as it is [abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

MemoryCache is **an actual implementation** of ObjectCache.

From the documentation:

[ObjectCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache.aspx)

> Represents an object cache and provides the base methods and
>   properties for accessing the object cache.

[MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx)

> Represents the type that implements an in-memory cache.

Looking at the declaration for MemoryCache:

```
public class MemoryCache : ObjectCache, 
    IEnumerable, IDisposable
```

We can see that MemoryCache inherits from ObjectCache - that is, it's an cache for objects that uses Memory as its storage - this is therefore *an implementation* of ObjectCache.

You could write your own; for example, DatabaseCache, which could also inherit from ObjectCache but instead it would use a database as the backing storage.

For everyday use, provided it met your needs, you would use and consume a MemoryCache. If you wanted to write your own, you could inherit from ObjectCache and implement the required methods and properties. However, in reality, there is probably little practical benefit to doing this as Microsoft already make several other caching solutions available, as do many other vendors.

Comment: To create your own, see [Creating the Custom Cache Class on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919782.aspx#Anchor_5)

Answer (score 17):

From [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx);

> The ObjectCache type is the primary type for the in-memory object
>   cache. The built-in MemoryCache class derives from the ObjectCache
>   class. The MemoryCache class is the only concrete object cache
>   implementation in the .NET Framework 4 that derives from the
>   ObjectCache class.

```
public class MemoryCache : ObjectCache, 
    IEnumerable, IDisposable
```

`MemoryCache` inherits from `ObjectCache`.

You can get a reference to the default `MemoryCache` instance like this;

```
public static ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
```

Answer (score 4):

`ObjectCache` is an abstract class, you can't 'use' it per se. As Dash says in his comment, it's designed to show how a cache should be built and what operations it supports. `MemoryCache`is an implementation of `ObjectCache` and from your question is likely what you should use. However, because `ObjectCache` is abstract, you could just as easily write your own `FileCache` inheriting from `ObjectCache` and it would be perfectly valid.